# WiX internet shortcut icon missing?

Tags: wix

I am using WiX 3.0.5301.0 I have code like

```
<Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="{0F889915-B241-414d-A5F6-E956AA60AAFD}">
  <util:InternetShortcut
    Id="Home"
    Directory="DesktopFolder"
    Name="Joy of Setup"
    Target="http://joyofsetup.com" />
</Component>
```

the shortcut appears but the internet shortcut icon does not appear? It is a blank windows icon? My user are gonna ask me where is the link on the desktop?

Any ideas? Did you have any issues? Does it work ? Is it a bug in this specific version? Should I upgrade? Rob? alloooo

Target OS Windows XP SP3
Browser Installed : IE 7
Also tested on:
Target OS Windows XP SP3
Browser Installed : IE 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using a .url file? on those you can even customize the icon.

Comment: a url file what IE saves in favorites as links to websites, you can customize it afterwards and include it into your installer as any other file.